# Can I get Factor or another command to pull out common factors that appear only in subexpressions of very complicated expressions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

This follows a comment I posted earlier, to which I received several responses but which was then closed. I have used Simplify and FullSimplify with Assumptions to reduce down some very complicated solutions of a 4-dim. system of 1st-order linear ordinary differential equations. But to completely simplify them, I need to factor out terms that appear only in parts of the solutions. Stylized example: I want to convert ax+ay+bx+by+cz to (a+b)(x+y)+cz. "Factor" per se does not do this. Is there some other way? (BTW, for what it's worth in case someone else raises this issue in the future: Before it was just suggested, I hadn't tried "Factor" b/c the documentation says it's for *polynomials*, and my expressions are not those as they're commonly understood - instead, they're linear combinations of hyperbolic functions. I just learned that MMA has a more expansive understanding of "polynomial.")

Comment: Thanks Ulrich for your response. I previously looked into Collect. The problem is that the full expression I'm trying to factor now has about 40 terms, with three blocks each having a different common factor. (And I have others that are longer.) To follow your example would mean I essentially have to do it "by hand" just to formulate the command. In that case, I might as well just copy and paste the blocks one at a time into Factor. This is a _very_ basic form of simplification. Does MMA really not have a way to do it?

Comment: In order to get any help with your problem, you'll need to post a "minimal working example", not excessive long, but clearly showing what it is you want to accomplish. Otherwise, people have to guess at what you're after.

Comment: This is essentially the same as my previous stylized example, but extracting any  illustrative sub-part of my actual expression exceeds the character limit for these comments: Consider `aCosh[t] + bCosh[t] + cSinh[t]`.   I want to simplify this to `(a+b)Cosh[t]+cSinh[t]`. Neither Factor nor "plain" Simplify or FullSimplify will do this. Does this explain what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Here is a "Simplify trick." `Simplify[p,q==biggerExp]` will do a lot of work trying to find and rearrange to get `biggerExp` out of `p` and then will replace that with the shorter `q`. Example `Simplify[a*Cosh[t]+b*Cosh[t]+c*Sinh[t],q==a+b]` returns `q*Cosh[t]+c*Sinh[t]` and then `%/.q->(a+b)` returns `(a+b) Cosh[t]+c Sinh[t]` `Simplify` is aggressive in extracting that longer expression. You just need to claim that a single unused variable is equal to your longer expression. And then replace that var after `Simplify` is done. Try this. Does it work? Can you see interesting ways to use this?

Comment: `expr = a Cosh[t] + b Cosh[t] + c Sinh[t]; expr // Simplify` evaluates to your requested form `(a + b) Cosh[t] + c Sinh[t]` You need either a space or `*` between terms being multiplied.

Comment: The example you posted in the comments is definitely minimal, but maybe a bit too minimal if fixing a couple typos and a single command solves it. What I meant is that your question should contain enough of your real problem to illustrate why using Collect/Simplify is unsatisfactory. One thing to keep in mind is that you can Map these functions to specific levels in your expression. So if doing Collect at the top level as in the posted answer doesn't work, make this into a function and Map it to the lower levels - i.e. the "blocks" you refer to.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. Now I have to apologize for wasting your time: I previously didn't pay sufficient attention to what I was reading, and it turns out that ``Collect[expr,{x1,x2}]`` was indeed what I needed. However, I've now encountered another problem involving that command. But to explain it... To show a simple example I just entered ``Collect[ax+by+cx+dy,x]`` and got output ``ax+by+cx+dy``. What am I doing wrong _now_?

Comment: You keep forgetting to put spaces in between variables. Also, you may wish to use {x,y} in place of just x if you want to group all your terms. I.e. Collect[a x + b y + c x + d y,{x,y}] seems to work.

Comment: Arrghhh.... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Collect[a x + a y + b x + b y + c z, x + y, FullSimplify]
(*(a + b) (x + y) + c z*)
```